# How to set a delay to a function?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I know this question can be answered in many ways but I need someone to do this for me. I want my animation to do its thing and then a random number pops up? Right now I have 2 functions in one click (I need that). I'm new to this and a simple formula would be great! Can anyone help, if you can it would be appreciated! Thank you!
THIS IS ALL THE CODE!

```js
startbtn = function() {
  $('.wheel').addClass('animated-wheel');
  setTimeout(setRandom('random') {}, 6000);
}

function getRandom() {
  var values = [1, 15, 30, 45];
  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

function setRandom(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = getRandom();
}

function refresh() {
  location.reload();
};
```

```css
.number {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 78px;
}

.wheel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 600px;
  top: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.animated-wheel {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst4s 2;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation: myfirst 4s 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 300px;
  }
  33% {
    background: black;
    left: 600px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  66% {
    background: red;
    left: 600px;
    top: 650px;
  }
  100% {
    background: black;
    left: 600px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 300px;
  }
  33% {
    background: green;
    left: 600px;
    top: 300px;
  }
  66% {
    background: black;
    left: 600px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
    left: 600px;
    top: 650px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>
<title>The Wheel!</title>

<body bgcolor="orange">

  <head>

  </head>
  <div class="wheel">
    <h1 class="number" id="random"></h1>
  </div>
  <button onclick="startbtn();setRandom('random');">Start</button>
  <button onclick="refresh()">Reset</button>






</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a syntax error in your `setTimeout()`:

```js
startbtn = function() {
  $('.wheel').addClass('animated-wheel');
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Remove animation class
    setRandom('random');
    $('.wheel').removeClass('animated-wheel');
  }, 6750);
}


function getRandom() {
  var values = [1, 15, 30, 45];
  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

function setRandom(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerText = getRandom();
}

function refresh() {
  location.reload();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>
<title>The Wheel!</title>

<body bgcolor="orange">

  <head>
    <style>
      .number {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-size: 78px;
      }
      
      .wheel {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        left: 600px;
        top: 300px;
        background: green;
        position: relative;
      }
      
      .animated-wheel {
        -webkit-animation: myfirst4s 2;
        -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
        animation: myfirst 4s 2;
        animation-direction: alternate;
      }
      
      @-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
        0% {
          background: green;
          left: 600px;
          top: 300px;
        }
        33% {
          background: black;
          left: 600px;
          top: 0px;
        }
        66% {
          background: red;
          left: 600px;
          top: 650px;
        }
        100% {
          background: black;
          left: 600px;
          top: 0px;
        }
      }
      
      @keyframes myfirst {
        0% {
          background: green;
          left: 600px;
          top: 300px;
        }
        33% {
          background: green;
          left: 600px;
          top: 300px;
        }
        66% {
          background: black;
          left: 600px;
          top: 0px;
        }
        100% {
          background: red;
          left: 600px;
          top: 650px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <div class="wheel">
    <h1 class="number" id="random"></h1>
  </div>
  <button onclick="startbtn();">Start</button>
  <button onclick="refresh()">Reset</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: It changes perfectly, but a number pops up before the change. Does that make sense?

Comment: @EastonAntony I'll take a look at it, can you provide me with any additional information? Also, what exactly is the change you refer to? thanks

Comment: The change is when the timeout is done. A number is there before the change. MAke any sense? I gave you all the info.

Comment: @EastonAntony I believe I understand what you are referring to, please take a look at the changes I've made.

Comment: @EastonAntony made some more changes to smooth out the animation

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but now its doing the opposite I want it to do. The number is there in the beginning but when the timer hits it disappears. And remove what number? Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: @EastonAntony do you mind taking another look, I think this is the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Nope, still doing the opposite. I want it to appear after the animation not during it. @MiroslavGlamuzina

Comment: @EastonAntony the `onclick` for the `<button/>` you provided still has the `setRandom(...)`  inside of it. I removed it from the HTML and added a `setRandom()` to the `setTimeout()`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Okay the number went away but now after the animation it won't pop up. Hope I'm not stressing you out too much!

Comment: IT WORKED! I forgot something you said! Much love. Thanks!

Comment: @EastonAntony, na I don't mind. So heres the order of operation: 1) the page loads, no number is present 2) Start is pressed, animation begins. 3) Animation finishes, new number appears. 4) The number stays on the page until the next time the start button is pressed and the animation is finished. 4) After an animation is finished, a new number is selected by random. Did I get that right?

Comment: Ahh perfect, glhf!

Comment: Right On! I have the refresh button to clear it but I couldn't do it without you!

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of more elegant way but here is correction of your error:

```
setTimeout(function(){  
    setRandom('random')
}, 6000);
```

Comment: It's perfect but before the change a number is there. HELP!

Comment: Remove class after setRandom('random') function. So new click events will animate too.

Comment: The function refresh?